# Open TFS Query results in VS 2010 with all nodes collapsed by default

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

When I open a TFS Query with hierarchical results in Visual Studio 2010, the nodes are expanded by default. I can click the [collapse all http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Dd286633.Icon_CollapseAll(en-us,VS.100).gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Dd286633.Icon_CollapseAll(en-us,VS.100).gif) button to collapse them, but is there a setting or extension that will open query results with all nodes collapsed by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not currently an extension to do that. Maybe you could write one :)

Comment: +1 This is probably the best answer to about half of the wish list features for things in TFS that should already be in production. :)